# Write operation result with springdata mongodb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I want see result of insert delete ect. (write operations)
I use Mongo version 2.6 and spring-data-mongodb 1.5.4 
I know that since mongo v 2.6 it is possible to see a WriteResult(http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/  see returns), is it possible to see it in spring-data-mongo?

Thanks !

Comment: What do you mean? Not a lot of detail here. Do you expect a result like what you currently get from the shell?

Comment: I need something like  <code>WriteResult result = mongoTemplate.insert(MyObject);</code>

Comment: Still not clear on what you are asking. This is an opportunity to edit your question and explain yourself better.

Answer (score 0):

The only place the [BulkWriteResult](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/BulkWriteResult/) that you are referring to is returned from is the result of operations using the [Bulk Operations API](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/).

This is introduced as of MongoDB 2.6 so it needs that version at minimum on the server in order to work. You will see these responses in the shell because as of that version all of the helper methods in the shell actually use the "bulk" variants of the commands "under the hood". So even when there is only one operation being invoked it is in fact using the "bulk" variant under the hood when connected to a server that will support it.

Bulk operations are implemented in the underlying Java driver, but you need to obtain that underlying driver collection object from your Spring mongoOperations context before you can invoke them.

As such, the method signatures and returns are not the same as the Spring Data implemented methods, but are the base driver methods. But of course you can still access these and use them in your code:

```
    DBCollection collection = mongoOperation.getCollection("collection");
    BulkWriteOperation bulkWriteOperation =
        collection.initializeOrderedBulkOperation();

    DBObject content = new BasicDBObject("field","value");
    bulkWriteOperation.insert(content);

    BulkWriteResult writeResult = bulkWriteOperation.execute();

    System.out.println(writeResult);
```

Maybe one day the integration will be more complete. But this is currently the one area where most framework implementations based on the core drivers are lagging behind. In truth the core drivers currently separate between the legacy methods and the bulk methods so any general implementation is best handled just as the helpers do in the shell for backwards compatibility reasons.